# Rice and Java.io.IOException: Unexpected status code: 404 Help appreciated

Tags: server, apache2, java, localhost

I tried to use ./synthesize.sh for Bayou on Ubuntu. Help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Ubuntu Version = 18.04

Installations = TensorFlow, sci-kit learn, flask, SDK java, and python 3 virtual-env

This is NOT a website issue.
Any ideas or solutions, help will be very much appreciated.

[New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aTwd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is server running any service on port 8080?
You should verify localhost:8080 using curl or netstat , other method

Comment: I tried doing netstat but can you clarify. What am I trying to find?

Comment: Apache2 is running on my localhost.

Comment: I dont know why your shell script is trying to connect localhost:8080. But you have mantion installation= flask. According to me your flask dev server should running on http://localhost:8080.

Comment: NEVER MIND, I fixed everything. All I had to do was change the port Apache was connecting to... New problem though!